# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Tags: python, pip, pynput

I am writing some basic code in visual studio code and I am trying to use pynput, but when I import the module despite the fact that I installed it using pip it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

I have tried to install it using pip3, but it doesn't work
I have also tried to install it using the path interpreter, but it still doesn't work
This is the code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))
```

Strange thing is that this code works in sublime text 3,
but doesn't work in neither visual studio code nor cmd.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package associations may be incorrect.

First, see where your IDE is running python.  it should be something like C:\programData\Python

Reinstalling the python interpreter may fix this.  Or try upgrading the pip, which uninstalls the old one, and pulls down the new one from the cloud.  Open a CMD windows, and type the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

This will give you a fresh pip installation.  Then try "pip install pynput"

If this does not solve the issue, uninstall your current interpreter, then go to python.org, and download and install the latest interpreter.  Upgrade the pip.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.2. I have tried upgrading pip and now it works in cmd, but still doesn't work in visual studio code. So will it help if I reinstall python? or how can upgrade interpreter?

Comment: @irakli What you can do is check that your IDE is pointing to the correct python interpreter.  If is pointing correctly, and is not working, then yes reinstall the interpreter.  Glad the pip upgrade worked!

Comment: Can you tell me how to check if my IDE is pointing to the correct python interpreter? (sorry to bother you)

Comment: @irakli Not a bother at all!  I personally use PyCharm, but I know many people who use Visual Studio for Python.  I discussed it with them, and they said it all depends on your version of VCS.  Use the link below for further reference.:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
 
I apologize for not knowing  right off, but I do not use VCS.
Good luck with Python!  I love programming in it!

Comment: Thanks again for you time.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to run it from within the IDE, check the paths in witch it calls the python interpreter.

if it's pointing to any conda installation try `conda install pynput` instead

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs create an "interpreter" for your project, which in python-speak means that the IDE set up a "virtual environment" for you. Virtual environments are great for managing dependencies across different projects. For example if you need one version of pynput for one project and a later version for another project, you can do this with two separate virtual environments, whereas if you installed pynput on your system, upgrading pynput would break your first project. [More info on virtual environments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/)

When you open command line and run `pip install`, this installs the package onto your system interpreter. You'll instead need to 'activate' your virtual environment and run the pip install there. You can find the path to your virtual environment by opening your interpreter settings in your IDE. Then follow [these instructions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) to activate your virtual environment and run the `pip install` on your project interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip uninstall pynput
pip install pynput
```

or

install pynput using conda

```
conda install pynput
```

Comment: conda v4.8.1 is not able to install pynput on ubuntu18.04, conda spits an error `PackagesNotFoundError`